# Chromium redirects some URLs to searchguide.level3.com

Tags: networking, firefox, chromium, malware

I am using Chromium browser in Ubuntu 14.04 and whenever I visit `localhost:8000` or `0.0.0.0:8000` my browser, it redirects to `searchguide.level3.com`.

When I try to access localhost through the command-line using `curl 0.0.0.0:8000` or with Firefox, it works fine. Only Chromium misbehaves as described.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does Chromium also redirect you if you start it with a temporary profile (right-click on its launcher icon)? If it happens only on Chromium, I would suspect a malicious browser add-on or something like that...

Comment: i tried it with a temporary profile and there is no redirects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a quick [DuckDuckGo Search for "searchguide.level3.com"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=searchguide.level3.com) reveals, this is a malicious site and there is lots of malware out there that makes your browser or system redirect web requests to their site.

As you say this redirection does not happen with other browsers or a temporary Chromium profile, my guess is that only your normal Chromium profile got infected. Maybe you find some suspicious add-ons in the `chrome://extensions/` Extensions tab, but it's also possible that the infection is hiding itself and sitting somewhere deeper.

Therefore I would personally recommend to nuke all your user's Chromium profile and settings and let it recreate them the next time you start it. Maybe you want to export your bookmarks and write down your stored passwords somewhere before that.

To delete all your user's Chromium profile and settings, exit all Chromium processes and then remove these two directories:

- `/home/USERNAME/.cache/chromium`
- `/home/USERNAME/.config/chromium`

Additionally, as just deleting the user profile has not worked on the first attempt, you can purge the whole `chromium-browser` package and clean all its global configuration as well, and reinstall it again afterwards. To do this, run:

```
sudo apt purge chromium-browser
sudo apt install chromium-browser
```

Next time be more cautious when you download stuff or visit shady links.

Comment: still not working after deleting the two directories.

Comment: Maybe you have to purge and reinstall Chromium additionally to nuking the profile again: `sudo apt purge chromium-browser ; sudo apt install chromium-browser ; rm -rf ~/.cache/chromium ; rm -rf ~/.config/chromium`. And make sure that no Chromium instance is running any more while you do this.

Comment: thank you very much! worked flawlessly after reinstallation. please edit your answer to accept it.

Comment: @AliFaki Great that it worked finally. I included purging and reinstalling the package into my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the problem, simply search for a good DNS server and use that instead. Google’s free DNS server works for me.

```
sudo vim /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base
```

Then put your nameserver list in like so:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Finally update resolvconf:

```
sudo resolvconf -u
```

Credits: http://subharanjan.com/get-rid-searchguide-level3-com-hack-solved/